# Difference between LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime

From the `java.time` library, I am using the static method `Duration.between` to calculate the time in seconds between two LocalDateTime.

Everything works as expected, except for the case below, where I should see a difference of 60 seconds, instead of 1500.

[image]
Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now().with(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY).withHour(0).withMinute(0);
        LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now().with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY).withHour(1).withMinute(0);
        System.out.println(Duration.between(endDate,startDate).toMinutes());
    }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you asking about the image or the code? They don’t show the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 25 hours or 1500 minutes between Saturday 00:00 and Sunday 01:00

Maybe do you want Sunday 00:00 and Sunday 01:00?

Comment: Just to clarify. Here is the interval I need to calculate:
Sat 10:00-24:00
Sun 01:00-04:00

Comment: The problem is that your Saturday meeting spans over 2 days.  It's actually Sat 10:00 - Sun 00:00.  There's no such thing as 24:00.  You will likely need to change your code to allow for meetings that last multiple days.  Or if that's not allowed, you need to use 23:59 instead of 24:00

Comment: That is the answer! Thank Justin!

Comment: any elegant way to check if time is 24:00 and translate it to 23:59?

Comment: It really depends on your code, but it sounds like if the endTime is ever 00:00, you would want to change it to 23:59

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the duration between Saturday morning at midnight (00:00) (or Friday evening at midnight, whichever way you prefer) and Sunday morning at 01:00.

The difference is 25 hours, or 1500 minutes. The result looks fine.